# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'useful_tools'

Tags: python, module, modulenotfounderror

I am a beginner in Python. I was learning from a YouTube Video. So as for modules, we are supposed to make a py file named "useful_tools", containing some functions and then import useful_tools and use one of the functions in it.
I made sure that I have saved useful_tools in the same folder as main file, and I wrote these 2 lines like the video:

```py
import useful_tools

print (useful_tools.roll_dice(10))
```

But I faced with the error:

```
----> 3 import useful_tools
      4 
      5 print (useful_tools.roll_dice(10))

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'useful_tools'
```

However, in the video the code had no problem.
Can you tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: Did you name it `useful_tools` or `useful_tools.py`?

Answer (score 0):

try importing the specific script. For example, if I have a script called sub_script.py inside a file called sub_package I might import it via:

```
import sub_package.sub_script
```

then I can use the functions in the script called sub_script.py that is inside the file sub_package.

Make sure you are using the same environment, for example, Jupyter notebook or VS code as the person in the video, that way you avoid anything complicating your code along.

best of luck